# GET request works on Postman but fail with RestSharp

Tags: c#, restsharp, get-request

I know that similar questions have been already posted in the past but I read a lot on the subject and still couldn't find an answer to my problem.
I have a GET request that works fine on Postman:

[image]

I translated it with the Code tool in C# - RestSharp and tested it with my plugin but somehow I always get the same error:

[image]

My C# - RestSharp code (It's the one I get with the Postman translator):

```
var client = new RestClient("https://..........."); //my url
     client.Timeout = -1;
     var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
     request.AddHeader("Cookie", ".........."); //my cookie
     IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

I tried adding all the headers visible in the Headers section:

```
request.AddHeader("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.29.0");
     request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
     request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
     request.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
```

without result. The Authorization type is No Auth. Any idea?
Maybe it has something to do with the fact that the response body in Postman is a plain text? The other requests I send that have a JSON response works perfectly fine.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try request.AddCookie method?

Comment: @daveBM I've tried anything but not this. Thank you very much, it works pretty well with AddCookie method! Please, post an answer so I can accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `request.AddCookie(cookiename, cookievalue);`